# sub query needed I think

Tags: php, mysql

I asked this question yesterday and  am reposting a very simple version of it to make sure 
there was no confusion as to what I am attempting.

```
adam    toyota
joe     toyota
rick    mazda

SELECT * FROM table WHERE  
  name LIKE adam
  and also return rows where name is not adam but have the same car as adam.
```

So a search for adam would return rows: adam & joe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = 'adam'
OR car IN (
    SELECT car FROM `table` WHERE `name` = 'adam'
)
```

The "name is not adam but" part is not really making sense, since you will get all adams anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have two parts to your query, one will get it all (Adam's row will always be returned... since the car Adam owns is always going to match the car from Adam's row `:)`):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE car IN (
    SELECT car
    FROM table
    WHERE name = 'adam'
)
```

Or the `JOIN` version, which may or may not perform better on MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table a
JOIN table b
  ON a.car = b.car
WHERE b.name = 'adam'
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the answer was downvoted.  I think the first answer incorporates a clever observation.

Comment: Note that if the **`(name,car)`** tuple is not unique, the JOIN form can return "duplicate" rows. Also note that if **`car`** has a value of NULL for **`adam`**, then neither query will return the row for 'adam'. (@Gordon: It wasn't me that downvoted, I think this is a good answer; I'm just pointing out some subtleties that won't be recognized in the limited sample data. With the sample data provided by OP, both of these queries work just fine.)

Comment: @mleko: I think the JOIN version returns the specified result for the sample data provided.

Comment: @spencer7593 I checked, it does :)

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . That was why I specifically commented about the first solution.  The second can easily be fixed by using `SELECT DISTINCT`, but it is prone to duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE 
car = (
    SELECT car FROM `cars` WHERE `name` = 'adam'
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f845/2

And to cover null car for adam problem

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE 
car = (
    SELECT car FROM `cars` WHERE `name` = 'adam'
)
OR
`name` = 'adam'
```

Comment: This query won't return a row for **`'adam'`** if the value of `car` on that row is NULL. This query works for the provided sample data; this differs from the OP specification on an edge case (not in the sample data).

Comment: @spencer7593 you are right, but then none of current answers is valid, it depends what we want to get

Comment: actually, the answer from Shredder meets the specification; though I think the queries in all of the answers return a "correct" result for the sample data.